# how can i fix Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a code which save and read data from json file , the code also use TKinter for UI . Now i managed to pinpoint when i get the error but not how to fix it, the error occur when i press the search button or the description button inside the UI , the error always occur if i have the "login_screen()" function start first, the error also causes the code to stop and exit to pycharm , here is the entire code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import json


def radio_used():
    global x
    x=radio_state.get()
    print(x)

#Listbox
def listbox_used(event):
    # Gets current selection from listbox
    print(listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

def show_list():
    global listbox
    listbox = Listbox(height=5)
    companies = []
    with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
        data=json.load(data_file)
        for item in data:
            companies.append(item)

    for item in companies:
        listbox.insert(companies.index(item), item)
        listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", listbox_used)
        listbox.grid(row=3, column=2)

##------------------------------------SAVE DATA----------------------------------------------

def save():

    bn = bname_entry.get()
    nm = name_entry.get()
    lc = location_entry.get()
    ph = phone_entry.get()
    eml = email_entry.get()
    txt = text.get("1.0", END)
    new_data = {
        bn: {
            "Name": nm,
            "Email": eml,
            "Location": lc,
            "Phone Number": ph,
            "Value": x,
            "Description": txt
        }
    }

    if len(bn) == 0 or len(ph) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="Please make sure you haven't left any fields empty.")
    else:
        try:
            with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
                #Reading old data
                data = json.load(data_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(new_data, data_file, indent=4)
        else:
            #Updating old data with new data
            data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                #Saving updated data
                json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
        finally:
            bname_entry.delete(0, END)
            phone_entry.delete(0, END)
            name_entry.delete(0, END)
            location_entry.delete(0, END)
            email_entry.delete(0, END)
            text.delete("1.0", END)

#----------------------------------------FIND DATA-------------------------------------------

def find_data():
    bn = bname_entry.get()
    try:
        with open("data.json") as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="No Data File Found.")
    else:
        if bn in data:
            email = data[bn]["Email"]
            name = data[bn]["Name"]
            location = data[bn]["Location"]
            phone = data[bn]["Phone Number"]
            status=data[bn]["Value"]
            messagebox.showinfo(title=bn, message=f"Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nPhone Number: {phone}\nLocation: {location}\nValue: {status}")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(message=f"No details for {bn} exists.")

#----------------------------------Get Description-------------------------------------------

def find_des():
    bn = bname_entry.get()
    try:
        with open("data.json") as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="No Description Found.")
    else:
        if bn in data:
            txt = data[bn]["Description"]
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Description", message=f"{txt}")


#-----------------------------------------Cypher---------------------------------------------

def cypher():
    global p1
    p1="test"

#-----------------------------------------User-----------------------------------------------

def user():
    global u
    u="user"
```

#-----------------------------------------Sign In----------------------------------------------

```
def sign_in():
    if p1=="test" and u=="user":
        login.destroy()
        main_screen()
```

#--------------------------------------Login Screen--------------------------------------------

```
def login_screen():
    global login
    #windows

    login = Tk()

    login.title("Login")

    login.config(padx=50, pady=50)

    login_canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)

    login_img = PhotoImage(file="rsz_dw-logo-final-removebg-preview.png")

    login_canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=login_img)

    login_canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

#labels

    u_label=Label(text="user Name:")
    u_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

    p_label=Label(text="Password")
    p_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

#entry

    global u_entry
    u_entry = Entry(width=21)
    u_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    u_entry.focus()

    global p_entry
    p_entry = Entry(width=21)
    p_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

#button

    p_button = Button(text="confirm", width=4, command=cypher)
    p_button.grid(row=2, column=3)

    u_button = Button(text="confirm", width=4, command=user)
    u_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

    s_button = Button(text="Sign In", width=15, command=sign_in)
    s_button.grid(row=3, column=1)


    login.mainloop()



#------------------------------------Main Screen---------------------------------------------

def main_screen():
    global window
    window = Tk()

    window.title("Data Manager")

    window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

    canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)

    logo_img = PhotoImage(file="rsz_dw-logo-final-removebg-preview.png")

    canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)

    canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)
#Labels

    bname_label = Label(text="Business Name:")
    bname_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

    name_label = Label(text="Name:")
    name_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    email_label = Label(text="Email:")
    email_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

    location_label = Label(text="Location:")
    location_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

    phone_label = Label(text="Phone Number:")
    phone_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

#Entries
    global bname_entry
    bname_entry = Entry(width=21)
    bname_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    bname_entry.focus()

    global name_entry
    name_entry = Entry(width=21)
    name_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    global email_entry
    email_entry = Entry(width=21)
    email_entry.grid(row=3 , column=1)

   global location_entry
   location_entry = Entry(width=21)
   location_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)

    global phone_entry
    phone_entry = Entry(width=21)
    phone_entry.grid(row=5, column=1)



    global text
    text = Text(height=5, width=30)
    text.grid(row=6, column=1)
    text_label = Label(text="Description")
    text_label.grid(row=6, column=0)



    search_button = Button(text="Search", width=13, command=find_data)
    search_button.grid(row=1, column=2)



    global radio_state
    radio_state = StringVar()
    radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(text="competitor", value="Competitor", variable=radio_state, command=radio_used)
    radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(text="client", value="Client", variable=radio_state, command=radio_used)

    radiobutton1.grid(row=7, column=1)
    radiobutton2.grid(row=8, column=1)

    company_list_button = Button(text="Show Companies List", command=show_list)
    company_list_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

    add_button = Button(text="Add", width=36, command=save)
    add_button.grid(row=9, column=1)

    des_button = Button(text="Description", width=36, command=find_des)
    des_button.grid(row=10, column=1)

    window.mainloop()

login_screen()
```

some quick info about the code : * def login_screen() function  gives a UI with 2 entries (user name and password) , * def main_screen() function gives UI with more entries but it only shows up if the username and password are correct which uses the *def sign_in() function*.

If i run my code with main_screen() at the end instead of login_screen() everything works fine when i use the search and description button , but if the login screen runs first , the two buttons i mentioned will cause my code to exit . Now if i wasn't able to explain properly my problem please past the code and try it for yourself to see what i mean exactly, if you do the user and pass for the login screen are : "user" for username and "test" for password (and click confirm for both entries) after that fill some stuff inside the main screen and click add , after that fill the business name again with the same name you used when you pressed Add from earlier and hit search or description and you will get the error , also remove lines : 148, 150, 200, 202 because these are images for the UI

Comment: In general, a SIGSEGV means there's a bug in C code, not Python code (or at least, _in addition to_ any bugs in the Python code: if the C code were written correctly, it would be throwing Python exceptions instead of segfaulting). The best tool to use here is a debugger like gdb to let you get a stack trace of where _inside the Python interpreter and any C libraries it loads_ the failure is taking place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i tried the debugger but couldn't understand what it said specifically, could you give me more help about the problem ?

Comment: If gdb has hit the error, use `bt` to get a stack trace, and edit that into the question; it may not be enough information on its own, but it'll at least get folks into the neighborhood of the problem.

Comment: BTW, as a general rule for getting a good response on Stack Overflow, we ask for a [mre] -- the _shortest possible_ code that causes the same problem. Building one may take some iterating -- take something out, test that the program still works enough to get to the problem, reverse it if not, take something else out, repeat, &c.

Comment: thanks for the help @CharlesDuffy i managed to fix the issue

Comment: Edit the question for [mre] guide. And please answer your own question if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) error

the problem is with import cv2. you need to use pip install numpy==1.24.3

this version of numpy fixed it. the newest version of numpy must be broken

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)